# jQuery not ready though still instantiating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery Class plugin as so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    window.SSK.calendar = new(Class.extend({
    filter_by_filtered_names: function() {
      console.log('foobar!');
    },
      init: function() {
        if ( window.location.href.match(/name_filters/) ) {
          SSK.calendar.filter_by_filtered_names();
        };
      }
    }))
});
```

For some reason this returns on load :

```
SSK.calendar is undefined
```

Which tells me that the plugin class is not loading before its own call. Very strange indeed. Curious if anyone knew a remedy?

Comment: I mean... shot in the dark and all... But are you sure that you are loading the plugin correctly?  That looks like an error that would popup if there was a problem loading the plugin.

Comment: why are you using 2 `ready` events?

Comment: Yes using it correctly. If I comment out the call then everything functions fine. And to note, this is a very large file with many methods and internal classes that also equally load fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour seems to make perfect sense to me, even if I don't know how `Class` works:

`Class.extend(...)` creates a new constructor function (I assume). `new` executes the constructor which in turn calls `init`. The result is assigned to `window.SSK.calendar`. You see, `init` is called upon instantiation and this happens before the instance is assigned to `window.SSK.calendar`.

Here is a simplified example:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.bar = 'baz';
    console.log(foo.bar);
}

var foo = new MyClass();
```

This will fail since `foo` is still `undefined` at the moment the constructor is called. The instance is the *return value* of the function call, hence `foo` cannot contain a reference to the instance *before* the call.

You might be able to solve your problem by simply using `this` to reference the instance:

```
init: function() {
    if ( window.location.href.match(/name_filters/) ) {
    // better in this case: if(/name_filters/.test(window.location.href))
        this.filter_by_filtered_names();
    };
}
```

The documentation of the plugin should mention how you can reference the instance from inside a method.

Comment: Well the only functional way I can get this to work was to move it outside and after the constructor method. But only with your incredible advice. This is the plugin: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ . Thanks so much Felix!

Comment: Yeah, but see, he uses `this` as well in the examples... didn't this work? It does here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/NksCL/

Comment: No, I threw a breakpoint inside the `init`, and this points to Document. `SSK` is instantiated, and its root methods, but the class Calendar is not.

Comment: Mmh. `this` should never point to `document`... Have a look at my demo, it works fine. Maybe something else is wrong as well...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you use two onReady listeners: `jQuery(document).ready(fn)` and `$(fn)` are exactly equivalent. Effectively, you will append the inner function to the end of the function queue when the outer function executes. When trying to access `SSK.calendar` in any onDOMready function that is not registered after that, it won't be available.

Example:

```
$(function(){
    console.log("A");
    $(function(){
       console.log("B");
    });
    console.log("C");
});
$(function(){
    console.log("D");
});
```

will log:

```
A
C
D
B
```

Comment: Updated but the problem still persists. Thanks though :D